# An isomorphic classification of non-associative division octonion algebras

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, non-associative-algebras

A *division octonion algebra* over a field $F$ is a $8$-dimensional unital non-associative algebra $A$ over the field $F$, endowed with a quadratic form $N:A\times A\to F$ such that $N(xy)=N(x)N(y)$ and $N(x)\ne 0$ for every non-zero elements $x,y\in A$.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion_algebra) writes that two division octonion algebras $(A,N)$ and $(A',N')$ over a field $F$ are $F$-isomorphic if and only if their norms $N$, $N'$ are $F$-isomorphic.
This reduces the problem of isomorphic classification of division octonion algebras to the problem of classification of their norms. Is there any additional information on such a classification?

> **Question.** *What is the number of non-isomorphic division octonion algebras over a given field? Can it be greater than one? Can it be infinite?*

Because finite or algebraically closed fields admit no division octonion algebras, see the lecture notes of [Konrad Voelkel](https://www.konradvoelkel.com/wp-content/uploads/voelkel-2015-01-27-basic-notions-division-algebras.pdf).

Comment: Your link to Voelkel's notes won't load for me.

Comment: @LSpice I use this link: https://www.konradvoelkel.com/wp-content/uploads/voelkel-2015-01-27-basic-notions-division-algebras.pdf

Comment: Same problem. www.konradvoelkel.com seems to be compromised.

Comment: With me it opens without problems

Comment: If you have wget (Linux should have it) you can download with `wget https://www.konradvoelkel.com/wp-content/uploads/voelkel-2015-01-27-basic-notions-division-algebras.pdf`

Comment: Oh I see now - both Chrome and Firefox do block the link; Brave does not.

Comment: Edge also has no problem opening the pdf in the above link.